# PHP-FPM suddenly very busy on NGINX web server

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a single wordpress site on a dedicated server at AWS running NGINX 1.22.1and PHP-FPM (8.1.2). Recently I’ve noticed a lot of entries like this in my PHP log:

```
[23-Oct-2023 07:02:26] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 25 total children
```

Normally I get this once in a while but recently it’s been many times a day.

I’m trying to pinpoint the cause but so far haven’t been able to. Would appreciate some advice.

I bumped up my pm.start_servers as well as min and max spare servers but it makes no difference.

I told PHP to log slow executions for a period and then looked at the log to see if I could identify something more specific.

Seeing quite a few entries like this:

```
[22-Oct-2023 08:29:15] WARNING: [pool www] child 34518, script '/var/www/html/sico/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php?_locale=user") executing too slow (12.463129 sec), logging
```

Also this:

```
[22-Oct-2023 08:29:15] WARNING: [pool www] child 34525, script '/var/www/html/sico/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php?add_to_wishlist=42938&_wpnonce=1209a21a51") executing too slow (11.478895 sec), logging
```

I also looked at the Waterfall in GTMetrix but not seeing any culprits. Maybe I’m missing something? Any advice on how to identify the cause of this issue so I can resolve it would be very much appreciated.